# Wordpress random 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress

Randomly i keep getting 500 internal server error and  I've checked server log the only errors displayed are:

```
End of script output before headers: admin-ajax.php
 End of script output before headers: index.php
```

I've increased php memory limit and wordpress memory limit to 256m.  I'm running a woocommerce shop. When i refresh a resource heavy page multiple times this is most likely when the error appears.  The error also randomly goes away after about 5 minutes.  I can still access the wordpress `readme.html`.  I've renamed the plugin folder and still the error remains.

Any idea what would be causing this?

Comment: Hi there. I have previously had a very similar issue. If any content (even whitespace) accidentally appears after a php file's closing tag it can be sent to the browser. This can cause this Issue. Check the files for any content after the `?>`

Comment: thanks, theme files or plugin files?

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add this as comment, but unfortunately I don't have enough points.

This can be because of some plugin messing with HTTP headers - have you installed some plugin/theme soon before the errors start showing?

Can you enable WP_DEBUG, to see if you can catch something there, as sometimes it is more useful than the server logs.

To do this, open

```
wp-config.php
```

located in the directory where WordPress is installed and then locate the line with the code

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

and change it to

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

That will save the log in a file called debug.log and located in your
`wp-content` directory. It is important step to set it log to a file, if you don't want to have errors thrown on the site.

You can also refer to this  [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG).

Comment: thanks, if i enable WP_DEBUG will frontend users see errors or will they just be displayed in the log file?

Comment: If you don't specify that you want the errors to be saved to a file, they will.
Just use paste the three lines from the answer replacing  define('WP_DEBUG', false);
And then let us know if there is something interesting in the error log.

Comment: I just checked `debug.log` i must of have it previously activated, the error that stands out is `PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away` also `PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet.`  .. Any idea?

Comment: The problem is that there is no connection to the MySQL server.
Tell that to the hosting support, and if they don't fix it move to another host.
This is assuming you are on shared hosting somewhere, if you are on VPS/Dedicated server you will need to dig deeper to understand why the MySQL server is down.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comment below (mysql server has gone away) and the random 500 (apache/http) internal server error, the server could possibly be under a heavy load.  It may be receiving more connections than it can handle until either apache or mysql are unable to respond.  I would check with the web hosting provider to verify if the issue is related to the server or your site specifically.

I've run into plugins with memory leaks and all kinds of issues.  If it is indeed something with your site, I would try disabling all plugins to see if this resolves the issue, then re-enable them one at a time trying to reproduce the issue.

So then, if you do narrow it down to one plugin - check for (and install) updates (after taking a backup), seek support from the plugin author, seek an alternate plugin, hire a developer, or simply go without it.

Answer (score 0):

With wordpress there is the possibility that the version of php that you are using may well be the wrong one.  Modern wordpress installations need 5.4 or above particularly if using jetpack.  I had the issue described by the OP running wordpress 4.8.1 with Jetpack configured and connected to my wordpress.com account when my server was using php version 5.3 I switched versions to 5.4 and the problem was immediately solved.

I hope this helps.